# exiflib.dll should be in release mode error while testing app with windows certification kit for windows 8

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-store-apps, wack

i am using exiflib.dll for windows application which is downloaded from [*ExifLib - A Fast Exif Data Extractor for .NET 2.0+*](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36342/ExifLib-A-Fast-Exif-Data-Extractor-for-NET-2-0). The app was building fine in my pc.But when i tested the app with windows certification kit,it was throwing an error for not using exiflib.dll in the release mode.I am using visual studio 2012 express edition for windows 8.How to solve this issue.Can anyone find a solution for this???Thanks in advance.

Errors i got while testing the app with windows certification kit is shown below.

Supported API test

FAILED 
Supported APIs
•
Error Found:

The supported APIs test detected the following errors: ◦API System.IO.FileInfo in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=7CEC85D7BEA7798E is not supported for this application type. ExifLib.dll calls this API.

◦API System.IO.FileStream in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=7CEC85D7BEA7798E is not supported for this application type. ExifLib.dll calls this API.

◦API System.IO.FileSystemInfo in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=7CEC85D7BEA7798E is not supported for this application type. ExifLib.dll calls this API.

◦API System.IO.FileInfo.OpenRead in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=7CEC85D7BEA7798E is not supported for this application type. ExifLib.dll calls this API.

◦API System.IO.FileInfo.get_Length in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=7CEC85D7BEA7798E is not supported for this application type. ExifLib.dll calls this API.

◦API System.IO.FileSystemInfo.get_Name in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=7CEC85D7BEA7798E is not supported for this application type. ExifLib.dll calls this API.

◦API System.String.Format(System.String,System.Object) in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=7CEC85D7BEA7798E is not supported for this application type. ExifLib.dll calls this API.

Debug configuration test

FAILED 
Debug configuration
•
Error Found: The debug configuration test detected the following errors: ◦The binary ExifLib.dll is built in debug mode.

•
Impact if not fixed:  Windows Store doesn’t allow a debug version of an app.

Comment: Where did you get the exiflib.dll from? Building yourself from source?

Comment: windows certification kit is only meant for Windows Store applications. So unless you recompiled the project in question to support WinRT you wouldn't be able to reference it within a project your trying to target to the Windows Store.  The last version release 1.4 does not appear to support WinRT.

Comment: If last version release of exiflib.dll is not supporting WinRT ,can anyone suggest a way so that it supports WinRT??The error thrown was exiflib.dll used is in debug mode.I am supposed to use that in release mode.I have just downloaded and used exiflib.dll from a project in this site [*ExifLib - A Fast Exif Data Extractor for .NET 2.0+*](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36342/ExifLib-A-Fast-Exif-Data-Extractor-for-NET-2-0) which is in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to download the project from github and compile again in release mode, and add the dll to your project

github url:
https://github.com/ravensorb/portable-exif-lib